# How to Fix Layering Issue with ::After

Tags: css, layer, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a stacked box look using `::after`. I created the code in a codepen (https://codepen.io/nk-creative/pen/vqvVJL), but when I place the code on the Wordpress site I am working on, I can't achieve the same stacking effect in the same order (http://aptw.nk-creative.com/)

I created the code in a codepen (https://codepen.io/nk-creative/pen/vqvVJL).

```
<div class="offset-boxes">
  <h4>47 Locations & Personalized Plans. Meet Your New Partner.</h4>
</div>


.offset-boxes {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 290px;
    background-color: lightpink;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 25px
}

.offset-boxes::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
  right: -40px;
  top: -40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

I expected the code to look like the codepen, but the WP site does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `::after` pseudo element is buried. You can add this to your CSS to the parent element of `.offset-boxes`:

```css
.textwidget {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]